# Изучаю JavaScript. Запутался в коллбэках, обьясните как и почему это работает

Tags: javascript

Функция debounce принимает в себя аргументом другую функцию (у которой есть свой аргумент "event") и возвращает функцию которая откладывает вызов функции-аргумента при наступлении события onInput.
Итак, внутри debounce происходит return с заданным параметром 'arg'. Из всего этого мне не понятно, каким образом и почему в return(arg) попадает именно аргумент функции "func" (то есть "event"), а не новый аргумент возвращаемой функции, например?

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Рабочий код приведен ниже:

```
 const debounce = (func) => {
        let timeoutId;
        return (arg) => {
            if (timeoutId) {
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            }
            timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                func(arg);
            }, 1000)
        };
    };

    const onInput = debounce((event) => {
        fetchData(event.target.value);
    });
    input.addEventListener('input', onInput);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не "в `return(arg)` попадает аргумент функции `func`", а в функцию `func` попадает параметр, с которым вызывается `onInput`.

Обработчиком события является то, что вернул вызов функции `debounce` (`onInput`). Этот обработчик содержит ссылку на `func` в своем замыкании и вызывает `func`, если после последнего события прошло больше секунды.

Comment: "в функцию func попадает параметр, с которым вызывается onInput" - если я правильно понял, в моем случае, в функцию func попадает "event" как параметр. Сижу, туплю но так и не могу понять, каким образом в return (arg) происходит обращение к этому параметру...((

Comment: @EugeneAdams `arg` это и есть `event`

Comment: То есть, если параметром принимаемой функции является передаваемая функция со своими параметрами, то в return, в скобках, я всегда имею доступ к параметрам передаваемой функции?

Comment: @EugeneAdams Это те же самые параметры.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: @EugeneAdams Пожалуйста. Успехов!